# Event fired twice using button box in Pyqt

Tags: python, drag-and-drop, pyqt, qt-designer

This app is a basic Drag'n'Drop program and should handle dropped .html files.

So far I have written this code:

main.py

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui 
import sys
import design, os

class MyTextEdit(QtGui.QTextEdit):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(MyTextEdit, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.list_of_dropped_files = []

    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasUrls():
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()

    def dragMoveEvent(self, event):
        event.accept()

    def dropEvent(self, event):

        self.clear()

        self.list_of_dropped_files = event.mimeData().urls()

        for single_file in self.list_of_dropped_files:
            self.append(single_file.toLocalFile())


class DialogInit(QtGui.QDialog, design.Ui_Dialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.buttonBox.accepted.connect(self.accept) # handle the ok button click
        self.textEditHandler = MyTextEdit(self.textEdit)

    def accept(self):
        print self.textEditHandler.list_of_dropped_files


def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)  
    form = DialogInit()                 
    form.show()                         
    app.exec_()                         


if __name__ == '__main__':             
    main()
```

and I created also a design.py code using the QtDesigner that looks like as follows:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'untitled.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt4 UI code generator 4.11.4
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Dialog"))
        Dialog.resize(409, 80)
        self.verticalLayoutWidget = QtGui.QWidget(Dialog)
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 401, 71))
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayoutWidget"))
        self.verticalLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayout"))
        self.horizontalLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("horizontalLayout"))
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label"))
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.textEdit = QtGui.QTextEdit(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.textEdit.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.textEdit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("textEdit"))
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.textEdit)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout)
        self.buttonBox = QtGui.QDialogButtonBox(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.buttonBox.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.buttonBox.setStandardButtons(QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel|QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Ok)
        self.buttonBox.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("buttonBox"))
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.buttonBox)

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.buttonBox, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("rejected()")), Dialog.reject)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.buttonBox, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("accepted()")), Dialog.accept)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog", None))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Drop .html file(s):", None))
```

However, after the Ok button from the button box has been pressed, the event and therefore the function accept(), is fired twice.

Furthermore I found that after dropping several files into the QTextEdit, the widget doesn't change its height or at least a scroll pane is added automatically.

Any ideas how to fix the both issues?

I think also that my code is pretty messed up, it works, but it is not really well programmed.

Can someone please give an advice how to refactor the code? What could I have been better?

Thanks!

Comment: Try renaming DialogInit.accept as it collides with inherited QDialog.accept.

Comment: Thanks! That worked, but when I now press the Ok button, the dialog is gone. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 0):

I've found myself a solution for closing the QDialog issue after the ok button has been clicked. I had to remove the accept() slot in the design.py.

However, I still can't see a scrollbar added when several files have been droppped.